# Cannot find WSL option inside Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Windows 11 system.

My project require to use a docker environment. In order to do so, I need to install WSL, a Linux terminal. And I meet problem in connecting WSL into Visual Studio Code.

**Step 1:** I already install WSL

**Step 2:** I also install WSL extension in Visual Studio Code.
[image]

Problem:
But when I need to use WSL comment from terminal inside Visual Studio Code, I cannot find WSL option...

[image]

Comment: Though your 'Ubuntu' terminal seems to indeed be missing, just run powershell or cmd in VSCode instead and then enter `wsl` to enter the WSL terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a linux distro on WSL, which from the screenshot you shared you do not have.

Ubuntu is the easiest, you can follow the steps here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support#1-overview

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the WSL for Docker Desktop directly.

Instead, you run all your docker commands from the *host* and it'll run them on the docker engine ran *in the background* in that wsl instance.

If you want a normal linux WSL installation, you have to install a distribution manually from the Microsoft Store. That one should then also appear in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

did you connect your workspace correctly?

in the right bottom there is a button, you should see WSL there. if you don't click on it and then choose connect to wsl:

[image]

[image]